# Equivalent of ORWHERE in Kohana 3 ORM model

Tags: php, orm, kohana-3

Self-explanatory title: how do you do an orwhere statement in Kohana 3?

eg:

```
$artist_check = ORM::factory('artist')
->where('name', '=', strtolower($itunes->artistName))
->orwhere('itunesId', '=', strtolower($itunes->artistId))
->find();
```

This statement throws an exception 'Invalid method orwhere'... As the K3 docs are abysmal I figured I'd ask y'all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kohana follows `underscore_notation`, so the method name is `or_where`, not `orWhere`.

Also [API documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Database_Query_Builder_Where#or_where) might be helpful.

Comment: aha nice job - thanks, was looking in the ORM documentation </fail>

Comment: But I have to say, the documentation in terms of navigability and/or accessibility for MVC n00bs like myself is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if this is wrong but as Kohana is a split of Codeigniter have you tried `->or_where();`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

**EDIT**

http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Database_Query_Builder_Where#or_where